# Will owls become extinct without airglow?

Tags: science-based, ecology, light, avian, vision

Given a planet in most ways very similar to Earth (gravity, daylight, atmosphere etc.) with a full transplanted biosphere (all the familiar plants and animals), where the main difference is that as a result of a combination of factors, the nights are much darker:

- No city lights; civilization has not been built here yet.
- No moon.
- For reasons to do with the background of the setting, there is much less air glow, which turns out to be the main source of light on moonlit nights in remote areas.

This creates problems for nocturnal predators.

Wolves are apparently mostly crepuscular (hunt in twilight rather than at night), so they should be mostly unaffected.

Cats on Earth have night vision so good that they can see by air glow where their prey cannot, so they positively like moonless nights, but I don't think even they can really see by starlight, so they will be negatively affected. But they are versatile enough that I think they will get by anyway.

Owls are a different matter. It seems to me that they are quite specialized nocturnal hunters and depend on having *some* light; with nothing but starlight, they will be largely shut down. Okay, they can still hunt by twilight, but that doesn't leave them much time in the day.

Will owls in that world simply go extinct?

Comment: Well, speaking only for myself, not for cats or owls, I can see just fine by starlight, not to read or any such fine skill, and certainly not recently as the whole thing has been mucked-up by the building of a motorway and airport with all its associated sodium lights. What makes you think cats and owls might have issues?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Because it turns out that when the apparent light source is starlight, most of the light is actually coming from airglow, which being diffuse is less noticeable but actually contributes a lot more photons.

Comment: Owls (and other nocturnal animals) got along just fine long before humans started polluting the nights with city lights, so point #1 is irrelevant.  They also do ok on moonless nights, likewise point #2.  Re point #3, they seem to survive in areas with lots of cloud cover, which blocks both starlight & airglow.

Comment: Airglow is about 65% of the night light on a clear, moonless night. Zodiacal light is about 27%, and direct starlight about 7%.. lose the airglow and you still have (27+7 = 34)% of the current light level remaining. That's a difference, but not huge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**it's hard to tell for sure, but probably not.**

(disclaimer: it's said that a single lit candle in the center of a football stadium would provide enough light for an owl to see the entire place clearly, their night vision is simply incredible. In here though, for the sake of simplicity, we'll  assume there's just not enough light).

It is true that owls are well known for their great eyesight, but something that is not quite as well known about them is that, especially so in nocturnal species, owls [also have great hearing](https://www.owlpages.com/owls/articles.php?a=6). Nocturnal Owls like the barn owl are especially adapted to hunt almost entirely based on sound. Thanks to their heads being structured in a way that funnels sound into their ears like satellite dishes and to their asymmetrical ears, owls can not only hear well, but also hear in 3 dimensions. This is also important to animals like the barn owl and the great gray owl because during winter, their prey is usually out of sight, hiding in tunnels beneath the snow, so being able to find them without seeing them gives these birds an edge over other more sight reliant raptors during the snowy season.

[image: owl skull depicting the asymmetrical ears]
*owl skull depicting the asymmetry of the ears, allowing them to pinpoint sound on both horizontal and vertical planes.*

The main problem I'd see here is that, without enough light, it'd be hard for an owl that can't see where it is going to avoid potential obstacles. However, we already have a species of owl that, having a night vision not that much better than ours, deals with this problem: the tawny owl. How does it solve the problem of flying at night without seeing the way? It just flies from memory by [mapping out its territory during the day](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2018/oct/25/country-diary-tawny-owl-finds-its-way-in-the-dark-dunton-bedfordshire), which not only is impressive, but gives us a good clue on how your owls would likely adapt, with owls with better memory and hearing ability being selected over other nocturnal owls that rely mostly on vision to navigate around the environment.

And even if all failed and the nocturnal species were to die for some weird reason, at the very least we'd probably still have the northern hawk owl and the northern pigmy owl around, given they're truly diurnal owls and thus essentially bypass a good portion of the low luminosity night issue.

Also a quick note: chances are that bats would thrive in this environment, since with nocturnal species becoming unable to hunt at night, their ability to echolocate suddenly becomes a massive advantage, and it wouldn't be surprising if it was to be selected among other species, which isn't that crazy since it's already seen in shrews, dolphins and [oilbirds](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.170255). You can be sure that owls will not be the only species affected by this dark night issue, but they probably won't be in the list of animals that will go extinct because of it.